# Using Gin: How to pass original JSON payload to a Redirect POST

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm a newbie when it comes to Go and Gin, so please excuse my ignorance.

I've setup a server using Gin which supports a POST request. I would like the user to POST their request which includes a required JSON payload redirecting that request to another URL. As part of the redirect I need to pass the original JSON payload. For example, if the user issues this CURL request:

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "name": "NewTest Network", "organizationId": 534238, "type": "wireless"}' -X POST "http://localhost:8080/network"

My Gin code does this:

```
r.POST("/network", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, networks_url)
})
```

where: networks_url is the redirected URL. I need a way to pass the original JSON payload to the redirected URL.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with Go or gin.

This is the expected behavior of a user agent, which should change the method from POST to GET with either a 301 or 302 redirect.

To instruct the user agent to repeat the request with the same method, use 307 (`http.StatusTemporaryRedirect`) or 308 (`http.StatusPermanentRedirect`).

Comment: Thanks, I used the http.StatusPermanentRedirect and it works.

Answer (score 3):

You must use **301** or **302** as a redirect status code.

```
c.Redirect(301, "http://www.google.com/")
```

Please refer the documentation [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Redirect).

Answer (score 0):

I've got the problem too many requests (loop), so I'm fine with this one.

```golang
if err != nil {
    session.AddFlash("The error I would like to show.", "error")
    c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/my/route")
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirect feature of HTTP doesn't redirect anything. It just notifies the client that there is a new URL to use, and the client has to use the new URL instead of the old URL.

Use the `-L` option (`--location`) option to `curl`, and `curl` will do all the work for you.

```
curl -L -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{ "name": "NewTest Network", "organizationId": 534238, "type": "wireless"}' \
  -X POST "http://localhost:8080/network"
```

Try running the same `curl` command with `-v` instead of `-L`, and you'll see that all of the redirection magic is in the response header.